# How can I remove high frequencies from a spectrogram, or from the original audio files?

Tags: spectrogram

I have been given sample audio files. Some are transcoded from low bitrate to high.
When I create a spectrogram using SoX I get frequencies extending up from 15kHz to 22kHz.
[image]

How can I either remove those high frequencies from the audio file, or alternatively create a spectrogram that doesn't show those frequencies?

Comment: To what end? If you want them to brick wall, just re-encode to 32k again.